# Left join adding all rows from right table

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

I noticed, when using updating by reference, I was losing some rows from my right table if there is more tan one row by join key.
No matter how I browse the forum, I can't find how to do it. Something escapes me ?
Even with `mult=` it doesn't seem to work.

Due to a performance and volumetry issue I would like to keep updating by reference.

In my reprex, I expected two rows for `a=2`

```
A <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = 12:15)
B <- data.table(a = c(2,2,5), b = 23:25)  

A[B, on = 'a', newvar := i.b, mult = 'all']
```

Thanks !!

Comment: There is only one row for 'A'  where 'a' is 2 and how does left_join return more than those in the left data.  When you do the `:=`, it is just updating the original table and it wouldn't expand the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a `list` column in 'B' and do the join and assign (`:=`) as `:=` cannot expand rows on the original data.

```
A[B[, .(b = .(b)), a], on = .(a), newvar := i.b]
```

-output

```
> A
   a  b newvar
1: 1 12       
2: 2 13  23,24
3: 3 14       
4: 4 15
```

Once we have the `list`, it is easier to `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
A[, unnest(.SD, newvar, keep_empty = TRUE)]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b newvar
  <int> <int>  <int>
1     1    12     NA
2     2    13     23
3     2    13     24
4     3    14     NA
5     4    15     NA
```

---

Or use a full join with `merge.data.table`

```
merge(A, B, by = 'a', all.x = TRUE)
   a b.x b.y
1: 1  12  NA
2: 2  13  23
3: 2  13  24
4: 3  14  NA
5: 4  15  NA
```

Comment: Ok, great, I will test on my real data. Is there another way to do this in ```data.table``` ? With ```merge``` or something else ?

Comment: @Discus23 you can use a full join with `merge`

Comment: @Discus23 i updated the post.

Comment: With ```all.x``` it seems all right. But you confirm I have to do ```A <- merge.data.table(A, B, by = 'a', all.x = TRUE)```, so A address changes ?

Comment: @Discus23 it is not all.x, as it is not a left join

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question and B. My desired output is obtained with ```all.x=TRUE```.

Comment: @Discus23 it was not your original query as in the new one, you have an extra value in 'a' that is 'b'. therefore all.x works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237188/discussion-between-discus23-and-akrun).